# PHP equivalent to C# `: base`

Tags: c#, php

What would be PHP code equivalent for snippets below:

C# Code :

```
class Composite : Component
  {
    private List<Component> _children = new List<Component>();

    // Constructor
    public Composite(string name) : base(name)
    {
    }
  }
```

PHP code?

I am sepcifically looking for `: base(name)` section. Complete code reference in C# can be found here http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternComposite.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PHP equivalent is

```
class Foo extends Bar {
    public function __construct($param) {
        parent::__construct($param);
    }
}
```

This is explicitly mentioned in the PHP [documentation for constructors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).

You should keep in mind an **important difference** between C# and PHP: in PHP, if you don't explicitly call the base constructor it will not be called at all! This is not the same as in C#, where the base constructor is *always* called (although you can omit the *explicit* call if a public parameterless constructor exists).

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for `parent` - the accessor for the parent class.

Via `parent` you can call the base class constructor: `parent::__construct($param, $param2)`

See: http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php

Note that this goes directly into the constructor, like so:

```
public function __construct($x) {
    parent::__construct($x);
}
```